# Opencart Recurring profiles error on checkout page

Tags: checkout, profile, opencart2.x, recurring

Hi every one i am using opencart Version `2.1.0.2`. I have created one sample profile, its for testing i have set it for daily. i have created one sample product and applied this profile on it. now on the  i am try to checkout this product from client side on the checkout page its showing me  Warning: No Payment options are available. Please contact us for assistance!

http://ocbilling.jigneshmistry.co.in/index.php?route=checkout/checkout

Can any one help me out.

Regards,
Jignesh

Answer (score 0):

First Enable shipping method from Admin panel if yes then you need to check under catalog/model/shipping/yourshippingmethod.php is there any restriction and one more thing like if you register while checking out i guess you might not see that issue